# SQL subquery to joins -

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Is it possible to remove the subquery from this SQL?

Table has 2 attributes "id" and "field"
Many field could have the same Id.

These table has many registers with the same Id and different Value

In need get all same Id values using one of them like filter.

```
select *  
from Table 
where id = (select id from Table where value = 'someValue')
```

I think it could be really easy but I don't know how to do.

Comment: replace that `=` with an `IN`

Comment: Why not use directly `where value = 'someValue'` instead of sub-query

Comment: I cant replace the subquery with this cause i could have many registers with the same Id.

Comment: ... where id in(...) ... looks most self-describing to me; joins make your query harder to read. Do not worry about speed - sql server internal optimizer should take care of such simple queries.

Comment: A join is not necessarily a replacement for an `IN` condition - those are semantically two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self Join can be done

```
select T.Id,T.Field
from Table T
INNER JOIN  Table  TT
ON T.ID = TT.ID 
AND TT.Value = 'someValue'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you over simplified your example too much but you could make this a little simpler.

```
select *  
from Table 
where value = 'someValue'
```

Comment: Not necessarily correct (when there are duplicate id's with different value values.)

Comment: Agreed. But it is impossible to tell what they want given the vague explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited (Correct Answer):**

What I assume your problem is:
You have a value. Let´s pretend it´s "testValue". Now you want to get the id of this value and find all other datasets with the same id. 
What has to be cleared is that, "ID" is not the Primary Key and is not Unique.

You should be able to solve this by a simple self join:

```
select t.* from Table t right join Table tt on tt.id = t.id where tt.value = 'someValue';
```

So because of the join you will get a result that returns simply the table. With the where clause you shrink the result to your value. You should get the set of ids.

**Old Answer:**

This should do the trick:

```
select * from Table a inner join Table2 b on a.id = b.id where b.value = 'someValue';
```

You mentioned only one table in your question. I think this must be a mistake. If not, you have to change only the `Table2` in my query. But that would have no sense as you could do a simple query, too:

```
select * from Table where value = 'someValue';
```

this would be the result of the first query with a self join.

Comment: @Namrehs Ok, I edited it to perform a self join. But then where is the use of this query and why not make `select * from Table where value = 'someValue'` ?

Comment: @NAMRehs - I noticed that, however in that case you don't need to repeat the table at all - it seemed likely to me that there are in fact two tables - it's one of a few confusions here to be honest

Comment: I cant replace the subquery with this cause i could have many registers with the same Id and different values

Comment: Ok @Tincho. Then lets find a solution for you. To understand your Problem: You have a table, id is not the PK. The IDs can be dublicated. You want to find the same id´s to one value. So you search for the value "test" and get and id back. Now you want to find all the same IDs. I will try to find a solution and edit my answer.

Comment: @Tincho I have corrected my answer. Should be the right one now.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select T1.* from Table T1 JOIN Table T2 ON T1.id = T2.id AND T2.value = 'someValue'
```